# Netezza grant right to create temp tables

Tags: netezza, sql-grant

In netezza, what is the syntax for granting a particular user the right to create temporary tables in a particular database?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to create temporary tables is considered an "administrative privilege" (as opposed to an "object privilege"), and the general syntax, cribbed from the [online documentation here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_grant.html):

```
GRANT <admin_privilege>[,<admin_privilege>...] [ IN <scope> ]
  TO { PUBLIC | GROUP <group> | <username> } [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

When connected to a database other than the SYSTEM database, this will will grant the ability to create temporary tables for that database only.  If executed while connected to the SYSTEM database, it will grant the ability to create temporary tables for all databases.

```
GRANT TEMP TABLE TO user;
```

If you want to be explicit about the scope regardless of the database you are connected to, you can use the "IN" clause.

For a particular schema:

```
GRANT TEMP TABLE IN database.schema TO user;
```

For all schemas in a database:

```
GRANT TEMP TABLE IN database.all TO user;
```

Or all databases:

```
GRANT TEMP TABLE IN all.all TO user;
```